# Unsure if vlookup, hlookup or index match needs to be made to fill out values in a X,Y,Z mesh

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup

I would like some help with an an Excel formula as I am unable to infer if I need to use `hlookup`, `lookup` or `index` match for this.

I have 3 columns of data but how can I create a X, Y, Z mesh. How can I create a formula, so that, in my table "This is what I have", reference the number 1 in Column X and Apple in Column Y located in "Table 1" and return the 1000 located in Column Z?

I would like the formula to output out the numbers 2000 and 3000 as well.

Basically, what formula can I use to get the numbers in red. The last table is how I would like the output to be shown.

[image: Screenshot of table]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions to achieve the results you are looking for. Try the following formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(1,($A8=$A$2:$A$4)*(B$7=$B$2:$B$4),0)),"")
```

Then drag it to fill the other cells.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You are spot on

Comment: @beckythelearner Good that it worked out for you. Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) to learn how to navigate say thank you on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMIFS:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS($C$2:$C$4,$A$2:$A$4,$A8,$B$2:$B$4,B$7)),"")
```

[image]